# Add ports on Packet Tracer 7

Tags: network, packet-tracer

how do you create new ports using WMIC-4ESW on my routers on packet tracer 7? both of my routers have 2 GigaEthernet and I used them because my 2 networks on each router. I need to be able to add more ports on my routers on packet tracer 7.

Thank you,

MT

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

1) Double click on the router.

2) In the physical tab turn the router off by clicking the power button.

3) The module section lists all supported modules just drag and drop them to an available slot.

- HMIC-4ESW will provide you switching ports.

4) turn the router on by clicking the power button.

Comment: This is wrong answer. The switching ports have no IP Address command.